# Python - Paramiko Getting error "object has no attribute "get_fingerprint"

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, public-key

decided to give Python a try for the first time, so sorry if the answer is obvious.

I'm trying to create an ssh connection using paramiko.  I'm using the below code:

```
#!/home/bin/python2.7

import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect("somehost.com", username="myName", pkey="/home/myName/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ls -l")

print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

Pretty standard stuff, right?  Except I'm getting this error:

```
 ./test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./test.py", line 10, in <module>
ssh.connect("somehost", username="myName", pkey="/home/myName/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
File "/home/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 327, in connect
self._auth(username, password, pkey, key_filenames, allow_agent, look_for_keys)
File "/home/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 418, in _auth
self._log(DEBUG, 'Trying SSH key %s' % hexlify(pkey.get_fingerprint()))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_fingerprint'
```

What "str" object is it referring to?  I thought I merely had to pass it the path to the RSA key but it seems to be wanting some object.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `pkey` parameter should be the actual **private** key, not the name of the file containing the key. Note that pkey should be a PKey object and not a string (e.g. `private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file (private_key_filename)` ).
Instead of pkey you could use the `key_filename` parameter to pass the filename directly.

See the [documentation](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SSHClient-class.html#connect) for `connect`.

Answer (score 5):

If you have your private key as a string, you can this on python 3+

```
from io import StringIO
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()  

private_key = StringIO("you-private-key-here")
pk = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(private_key)

ssh.connect('somehost.com', username='myName', pkey= pk)
```

Particularly useful if your private key is stored in an environment variable.

Comment: I think you forgot to use io.StringIO.  I see you reference it, so you obviously intended to use it.  Your current example yields the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines' `.  To fix, change the line `private_key = "you-private-key-here"` to `private_key = io.StringIO("you-private-key-here")`.  Thanks for your comment, it helped me with the same exact problem the OP posted about.

Comment: my god, someone please edit this answer so that it has less syntax errors.